# Как верифицировать payment information аккаунта Heroku из России?

Tags: heroku

При попытке создать приложение, получается это:
Creating app... !
!    To create an app, verify your account by adding payment information. Verify now at https://heroku.com/verify Learn
!    more at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification

**Можно ли зарегаться через карту QIWI? Или нужно оформлять международную карту через сторонние сервисы и уже заходить через неё?**